# Detect if PHP file directly loaded

Tags: php

I'm using some PHP pages do some AJAX stuff but I don't want them to be directly accessible.  Facebook does a similar thing so for example: domain.com/ajax/my_ajax_form.php

If I was to load that page using AJAX it would work fine, but if a user were to try and loading the file directly by typing in that url it would do through an error so e.g.

```
if( IS FILE LOADED DIRECT? )
{
header ( HTTP/1.0 404 );
}
```

Comment: What would be the reasoning to have it limit access to the file? Usually direct access means, just calling the file `ajax.php`, I would have it default to an error message unless they add GET or POST vars, like `ajax.php?method=getData`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible.  You cannot rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']`, and even if you could, it doesn't matter.  Anyone can send the same request to your server that your browser does, via `POST` or `GET`.

What you should do is validate the request, and return the proper result if it is valid.  If it is invalid, do not return a 404.  (Browsers can cache errors like 404.  If your client-side code had a trouble, subsequent requests may fail!)  If the request is invalid, return an error of some sort.

Again, it is *impossible* to secure stuff like this.  You should be validating the session and request data.  That's all.

Comment: +1 I totally agree, if it is being consumed by an ajax request, just make sure it is secure from that perspective and what the output is. I wouldn't waste my time with blocking non ajax requests.

Comment: You can certainly rely on it, if you can hold all threads in your own hands. Albeit, the header is not a standard in any way, but common practice none the less. And application security should be handled on a lower level in the application anyway, not by denying access to resources depending on access method.

Answer (score 5):

You can look for the `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH` header.

```
$is_ajax = array_key_exists('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH', $_SERVER) 
           && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] === 'XMLHttpRequest';

if (! $is_ajax) {
    die('go away.');
}
```

Note, though, that it's not standard, but needs to be set explicitly on the requesting side. AFAIK, at least jQuery and Mootools set it though, probably most others as well, but don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to only access that page via `POST`, and not via `GET`. Though keep in mind - if a browser can do it - then a hacker can too.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use *session variables*, or more generally, *cookies.*

**With cookies:** (set in JavaScript)

1. JavaScript: Set token in cookie
2. JavaScript: Make XMLHttpRequest
3. Server side: Check token from cookie
4. Server side: Return JSON output or error message

Please note that **this is no way secure**! This just prevents easy linking.

**With session variables:** (cookies set in server side)

1. Server side: Authenticate user, set privileges
2. JavaScript: Make XMLHttpRequest
3. Server side: Check privileges
4. Server side: Return JSON output or error message

This method is as secure as the user authentication is.